# Power analysis after placement and routing of ASIC

Tags: design, routing, asic, cadence

How can I procure the files stating the details of power consumption of the chip after PNR in SOC Cadence Encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a script or flow to automatically run STA after routing, you need to run the `report_timing` command. If you're running some type of script, check the log (or the script itself) to see if a timing report has already been generated. It depends on your (or your lab's) environment and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'report_power' at any stage of the flow to find out the power measurements.